# Импорт python-библиотеки LDTP на удаленной виртуальной машине через SSH

Tags: ubuntu, сокет, ssh, python-2.7, kubuntu

С виртуальной машины Kubuntu 16.04 через SSH подключаюсь к другой виртуальной машине Kubuntu 16.04, в терминале ввожу команду 'python', затем ввожу команду 'from ldtp import *', после этого и возникает ошибка.

[image: подключение по SSH к удаленной машине уже выполнено]

Библиотека LDTP - не стандартная, при этом импорт стандартных библиотек выполняется без ошибок 'import os', 'import sys'.
Не пойму, что нужно изменять, настройки SSH или настройки Python. Если есть какие мысли, то подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Текст ошибки следует в виде текста (с форматированием) добавить, а не картинки, Чтобы людям с похожей проблемой, легче было бы этот вопрос найти. Если не знаете как из терминала текст скопировать, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: "Connection refused" может быть вызвано разными обстоятельствами, независимыми от Питона. Убедитесь что необходимые сетевые сервисы запущены и что доступ к ним не ограничен (порт не отфильтрован, соединение устанавливается хоть каким-то способом).

Comment: Спасибо. Соединение устанавливается без проблем, не получается только импортировать единственную библиотеку ldtp.

Comment: Что значит "порт не отфильтрован"? Как это проверить?

Comment: 1- Соединение НЕ устанавливается (посмотрите, что фраза: "connection refused" означает). Проверять следует с той же машины, где вы пытаетесь скрипт запустить. 2- "порт отфильтрован" -- ограничивает ли firewall соединения по указанному порту. Всё это к Питону не имеет отношения.